How to deal with mistakes or embarrassing moments in front of peers?
I am a post-doc (just finished PhD) and today my advisor asked me a question in a meeting. And I answered wrong. He laughed at me and asked me "Who taught you that subject??" in front of the
PhD students.
I was embarrassed and I realized I never really learned about it before. My university in my home country is very poor with zero government support and our education system was so bad.
I graduated with a master's and a PhD because I tried so hard and basically I had learned by myself throughout the graduate study years from online and books. I know I am lacking in many areas. But after today,  I really depressed and lack of self confidence. I feel like no matter how hard I try, I will never be it.

This doesn’t seem to have anything to do with academia, other than that it happened to you in academia. The interpersonal SE may be more appropriate for this.

Is this your PhD advisor? Is it possible they meant to be self-deprecating since they are the one who taught you?

Are you certain this remark was meant as a criticism or a "put-down" rather than simply an off-hand jest meant in a jovial light-hearted manner? Hard to tell from your description.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion or containing answers will be removed.

First, the put-down from the PI was unkind and shouldn't have been said.
Second, it is natural to feel dumb when something like this happens. And it probably happens to just about everyone in some context.
Third, you don't, and can't, know everything and you can admit it to yourself and to others. Apparently nobody taught you that and you probably didn't think about it previously, leading to an error. But it is also possible that somebody taught you wrong and misled you. I had a student once who had serious misconceptions about how math works in computing and in simple equations. It was the fault of an earlier teacher who drilled in the error, but was trusted.
Finally, you are very probably competent in your field, having earned a doctorate. Don't let "imposter syndrome" develop in your self perception. But when you find a gap that is important to fill, fill it.

He is usually a very cool person, so I was so shocked today when he reacted like that. But anyway I will improve myself more, what else can I do, I just started this position. I’ll try to move on and be a better person.

Just focusing on the situation, I think it is really rather common, particularly in a group in which there are mixed backgrounds and somebody is the only one from one particular background, that there are a few things where one person is alone in not knowing something that the others know and kind of take for granted. I think most if not all of us have found ourselves in a situation in which we didn't know something that people around us knew and had difficulties understanding why we wouldn't know it. People tend to forget how heterogeneous experiences and backgrounds can be, and what this implies.
If such a thing happens just once or very rarely, I wouldn't worry much about that, but of course if you feel there is something important for you that you should know, you should make an effort to learn it (as apparently you have made many times before).
It may even be that the advisor didn't mean it all too seriously and would be surprised if he knew that you are now depressed because of it. As I wrote, such situations are rather common and most people are at the receiving end of ridicule because they don't know something that some others know once in a while.
Of course there is no way for us here to assess your general competence based on this story.

Thank you for your answer. I feel more positive now. There may be a cultural difference between my advisor and me (I am Asian, and he is Western). I completed my graduate studies in Thailand; I moved there right after finishing my bachelor’s degree in my home country. Everything was quite serious back there. I also just started this position two weeks ago. With a new country, new environment, and new employer, I may not have adapted well yet.

@Purplehour I (European) know a number of people who would make remarks like your advisor did in an entirely humourous way, even to their friends and family. Of course it would be better to be careful with this kind of humour with people who come from a background of which one has limited understanding, but in my view it is very possible that the remark wasn't meant in a serious way.

One more remark I want to make here is that advisors (professors, group leaders, etc.) are rarely good experts in psychology or mentoring. Very often they just have been "promoted out of their field of expertise". They were good scientists who were then promoted until their duties encompass everything except science. Usually they have little or no training in psychology, management, accounting, acting in public, intercultural relationships, etc. but have to do that most of the time. That's why their jokes can be dull or inappropriate. Good if they have enough self-reflection to realize that.

As an example, about 10 years ago I attended a PhD defence of my friend in Paris who then applied for a position in a company (in industry), and a person from that company's HR was present at her defence. The advisor made an inappropriate joke about her performance without thinking too much, which possibly cost her the job.

Perspective: A Healthy Environment
I'm over 50 with long stretches in both academia and industry.  That's long enough for me to have acquired a thick portfolio labeled Stupid Things I've Said In Public. Some of those have garnered similar reactions to what you describe-- not the exact words, but the sense of, "What the heck did you just say?"
In a normal US-based environment, that can be (but isn't necessarily) a sign that people are comfortable with each other to say things like that.  It can still sting.
One thing that helps is perspective:  If I pointedly asked, I'm sure a few co-workers remember the time I thought gold was more conductive than copper.
But I am quite certain that this is not the first thing that comes to mind when they see me, and therefore, it's unimportant and in the past.  Also, everyone does things like that from time to time.
Perspective: An Unhealthy Environment
Not all working environments are healthy, and sometimes, jerks will take advantage of a healthy environment.
It's not always easy to tell which you're in, though.  One sign of an unhealthy environment is if this sort of thing happens constantly.  Another is if it's always the same person catching the criticism.
A third, more subtle, is how people react when you ask for help/clarification.  This is a little more tricky when you have a PhD and are firmly in the "go teach yourself" part of your career.  (And I note that you did, which is good!)  But if you or another member of your group-- especially a more junior one-- are in a position where help is needed, the way in which that help is delivered (or not) can speak volumes.

Wow, today I learned gold is not more conductive than copper! Gold coatings are used for their chemical inertness rather than for their conductivity.

@BasilBourque ...and it's something I really should have known, at the time and place I said it.  Totally unforced error.

The way how you reacted to this situation by searching the right answer and learning from it means you are on the right way. Such embarassing moments are common, but thanks to them you learn things you will never forget, which at the end makes you an expert in your field. Don't be discouraged by that but see it as an opportunity.

This is not a question about academia, but about interacting in a professional group of people.
What happened to you will happen again and there are two components to your reaction: your natural character and experience.
Best case: an extrovert, assertive person with a lot of experience. They will turn this to their advantage (either earning "what a nice guy" badge, or by even pushing their position by ridiculing the ones who laughed (aka hardcore politics)
Worst case: an introvert with a sentiment of "inferiority" to whom this happened fo the first time. This looks like the end of the world, your career and your social life.
The thing is that this is not. After the round of laugh everyone will forget that. The smoother you let go, the less drag there will be.
It is very easy to say this for someone who is rather in the first category (in the sense that I do not care and I will play this cool) but this is something that you ought to try to learn.
We have in France a saying: l'esprit d'escalier. This is the situation when you have a hundred excellent answers and behaviors, an hour or a day too late. Face them. Think about them. Replay them in your head. Put yourself again (in your head) in that situation and say loud, louder than you would do it normally, the responses (preferably when there is no one around :)). With time this will become second nature. In some countries this is a must because of the culture (it does not have to be toxic at all, it may just be how people react and how they do not hold on afterward)
TL;DR: this is normal, happens to everyone, get over it, and learn to react. Improvise. Adapt. Overcome.

Respond with humility. See yourself as a life-long student; do not expect yourself to know the right answer to a question when it is asked, and be eager to learn it.
When your advisor responds to your ignorance with something like the cruelty you describe, @camden_kid's comment is spot on - that is your advisor's embarrassing moment. The humble response then is to try and help your advisor save face, by responding as though he meant it as a joke. Don't let it be about you. ;)

Researchers become good by discussing a lot with other researchers, in particular asking questions, proposing ideas, trying to give answers, ... Unavoidably, because we are all humans, sometimes questions are naive or silly, sometimes answers are just plain wrong... It may hurt one's feelings a bit, but the mistake would be to protect oneself by reducing interactions with others. On the contrary, good researchers move on and keep talking to others in order to learn and improve.
Take it as badge of honour: we're here to learn, and mistakes are part of this process of learning.

When I was studying for my MSc, I asked one of the lecturers about an unfamiliar mathematical symbol. He laughed at me and said if I didn't know that I shouldn't be studying his course, and then told me several times I had to drop his module because I didn't know enough maths. I ignored him and eventually got just over 70% in his module (in the UK this is the cutoff for the highest grade boundary). I was never particularly concerned about this, I just mentally wrote him off as a jerk and a bad teacher.
I have also made people feel stupid in the way I reacted to something they said. Either by laughing in surprise, or sounding overly incredulous when asking why they think that. Some of the times I've reacted in this way, I was the one who had the facts wrong! I recognise that this is a flaw in how I talk to people and is something I'm working on changing, because that's not how I want to make people feel when I talk to them. When I react in that way, however, it's definitely not because I think they're stupid, and when I first found out that this was how I was making people feel I was really upset.
How people react to you making a mistake or not knowing something says more about them than it does about you. If you make a mistake and someone responds mockingly, try to treat the conversation as a collaborative exercise in making sure everyone is on the same page. Treat it as a learning opportunity even if they're being a jerk about it. If they're not intending to be rude it will diffuse the situation, and if they are intending to be rude it makes you look like the more mature person. For example, you could have responded "I'm mostly self taught in that subject, could you explain where I've gone wrong?".
As a final example of how this kind of conversation can go positively, I remember asking a question of one lecturer during my MSc - something along the lines of "you said A earlier and B just now, but they seem to contradict each other, have I misunderstood something?". He laughed and said "you've got me there", and explained the mistake he'd made in thing A earlier. Nobody thought less of him for making the mistake, and I still remember it years later as an example of someone graciously handling a mistake being pointed out in front of a room full of people.

I agree with the other answers that your advisor's behavior was rude and inappropriate.
In addition to those answers, some perspective may be useful.
What happened to you -- not knowing the answer to a basic question in a certain area (if it is indeed a basic question) is completely normal, not just for students, but also for professors!
Indeed, everyone is a novice in most fields other than their own.
For example, a PI who works in a very applied field may be completely unaware of basic questions and concepts in theoretical areas, and vice versa.
In fact, this is the point of academia, that we are always learning more! No one person can understand every subject, and the point of research is to learn and to understand more.
In the future, when you receive such questions, you can always respond honestly, for example:

I actually did not take that class as an undergraduate so I am a bit rusty on the details, so I would have to brush up on that. Can you recommend a good textbook?

or:

It's a bit embarrassing but it has been a long time since I studied as an undergraduate! I'll have to review that definition.

It is never a shame to not know; it is only a shame to stop learning more.
